# mysql Function giving no returns

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Test]
( @perm_sec_id  VARCHAR 
)
RETURNS
@temp_basic_bd TABLE
(
        fs_perm_sec_id varchar(50) , 
        currency varCHAR,
        P_price FLOAT
)
AS
BEGIN
  -- routine body goes here, e.g.
  -- SELECT 'Navicat for SQL Server'

INSERT into @temp_basic_bd
SELECT FS_PERM_SEC_ID,CURRENCY,P_PRICE from fp_basic_bd 
WHERE DATENAME(dw, [DATE])='friday' 
and FS_PERM_SEC_ID=@perm_sec_id;

  RETURN
END
```

after this i tried to execute my function

```
SELECT * FROM Test('B00242-S-US');
```

its giving 0 values

Comment: T-SQL not MySql surely.  Your function returns nothing as it selects nothing (the insert-select does not count) If you want to return the inserted rows look at OUTPUT INTO.  (You also don't specify a size for the varchar and the column count does not match)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the problem solved. Parameter size was not given